# Discord.js V12 syntaxerror unexpected token "{"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js v12 and I'm trying to make a account that adds a role or removes it if the user already has the role but I get error `SyntaxError: unexpected token "{"` I tried to find what's wrong but couldn't find anything please help

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'notifications',
    description: 'Adds/removes the order ping from you',
    aliases: ['notif'],
    execute(message) {
        pingrole = '809748975162359809'
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(c => c.id === "Cybers taco stand employee") {
             if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "orders ping")) {
                 message.author.roles.add(pingrole)
                 message.channel.send("Added your orders ping")
             } else {
                 message.author.roles.remove(pingrole)
                 message.channel.send("Removed your orders ping role")
             }
        } else {
            message.channel.send('You are not an employee')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work I tried rewriting the code and it still throws the same error

Comment: Please check your error messages, these are pretty clear. There was a missing `)` in `if (message.member.roles.cache.some(c => c.id === "Cybers taco stand employee")) {`.

Comment: Ah sorry I'm coding with low JavaScript experience thanks so much, I get stuck on stupid things most of the time

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the variable and you were missing one ")" at the end of if statement.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'notifications',
    description: 'Adds/removes the order ping from you',
    aliases: ['notif'],
    execute(message) {
        let pingrole = '809748975162359809'
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(c => c.id === "Cybers taco stand employee")) {
            if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "orders ping")) {
                message.author.roles.add(pingrole)
                message.channel.send("Added your orders ping")
            } else {
                message.author.roles.remove(pingrole)
                message.channel.send("Removed your orders ping role")
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send('You are not an employee')
        }
    }
}
```